# Cannot use FITSIO in Julia

Tags: package, julia, fits

I just started using Julia and installed the FITSIO package. When loading it I get the following error

```
julia> using FITSIO
[ Info: Precompiling FITSIO [525bcba6-941b-5504-bd06-fd0dc1a4d2eb]
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: extra token "ImageHDU" after end of expression
Stacktrace:
 [1] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [2] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
 [3] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [4] top-level scope at none:2
 [5] eval at .\boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [6] eval(::Expr) at .\client.jl:389
 [7] top-level scope at .\none:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\romain\.julia\packages\FITSIO\WueGk\src\FITSIO.jl:54
ERROR: Failed to precompile FITSIO [525bcba6-941b-5504-bd06-fd0dc1a4d2eb] to C:\Users\romain\.julia\compiled\v1.0\FITSIO\mbga9.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:313 [inlined]
 [3] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1184
 [4] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:311 [inlined]
 [5] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:941
 [6] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:852
 [7] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:311 [inlined]
 [8] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:834
```

I tried to remove and add again the FITSIO package, but I always get the same error. The stacktrace seems to go to line 54 of FITSIO.jl So here is the content of this file from line 46 to 57

```
import .Libcfitsio: libcfitsio,
                    fits_assert_ok,
                    fits_assert_isascii,
                    TYPE_FROM_BITPIX

# HDU Types
@compat abstract type HDU end

type ImageHDU <: HDU
    fitsfile::FITSFile
    ext::Int
end
```

Do you know how to make this package work?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer from the FITSIO developers:

> The latest stable version of this package isn't compatible with Julia
>   1.0. This has been already fixed in the development version, but we haven't tagged a new version since then.
>
> Remove FITSIO.jl with
>
> ```
> pkg> rm FITSIO
> pkg> update
> pkg> add FITSIO
> pkg> dev FITSIO
> ```
>
> After the rm, make sure you don't have any FITSIO.jl leftover, then
>   you can reinstall and switch to the development version within the
>   package manager, without installing another package

Comment: Yeah, there's some temporary turmoil in the Julia world as it has graduated to v1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Julia automatically fetched the wrong package with

```
add FITSIO
```

I solved the problem by forcing the download URL to be

```
add https://github.com/JuliaAstro/FITSIO.jl
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen.  Looks like perhaps there's a package bug.  Would you file an issue at [FITSIO.jl](https://github.com/JuliaAstro/FITSIO.jl/issues)?

Comment: Good idea, I reported the issue to FITSIO !